# Obscure websites on Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security

I need to use some sensitive websites (personal mails, banks, etc.) in Firefox in a public place.

How can I obscure the screen content so that people passing by wouldn't immediately know that I am on, say, Citibank site, or GMail?

I would prefer a solution for Firefox, but non-FF solutions are also welcome. For example, if I can obscure a particular windows on Windows 7 (say by turning it into negative image) I guess that would be cool too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always do simple things like turning off images in firefox (depending on how much that screws up your bank website's navigation) or turning off the stylesheet: View, Page Style --> No Style

You can use that same menu to shrink down the fontsize so perhaps only you can read it.

Comment: they also have sticky sheets to put on displays for hippa compliance in the us.  that way if they try to view from slanted angles, they see black

Answer (score 2):

For increased privacy, you might want to consider a [privacy screen](http://www.provantage.com/3m-98-0440-4965-2~7SMC908N.htm).

[image: privacy screen]